# Playframework 1.2.7 interceptors

Tags: playframework-1.x

There is a problem with PlayF 1.2.7 interceptors. 
I have a controller AuthCtl with @Before annotation.
And another controller class AlarmCtl which uses @With(AuthCtl.class).

```
public class AuthCtl extends Controller {

    public static final String KMK_AUTH_TOKEN = "KMK_AUTH_TOKEN";
    public static final String KMK_USER_ID = "KMK_USER_ID";


    @Before
    static void checkAuthorization() throws KomekException {
        if (request.cookies.containsKey(AuthCtl.KMK_AUTH_TOKEN) && 
                request.cookies.containsKey(AuthCtl.KMK_USER_ID)) {
            //Something
        } else {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    }

    @Catch
    static void handleExceptions(Throwable t) {
        response.status = ((KomekException)t).getErrorCode();
        response.accessControl("*");
        response.contentType = "application/json";
        renderText(t.toString());
    }
}


@With(AuthCtl.class)
public class AlarmCtl  extends Controller {
    //Something
}
```

So when I'm throwing exception in the checkAuthorization method my handleExceptions method doesn't intercept it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what type of exception(s) you want to catch.

So in your case it would need to be written like this:

```
@Catch(KomekException.class)
static void handleExceptions(Throwable t) {
    response.status = ((KomekException)t).getErrorCode();
    response.accessControl("*");
    response.contentType = "application/json";
    renderText(t.toString());
}
```

Or, for a general (kind of dirty) catch all, use the root Exception class:

```
@Catch(Exception.class)
static void handleExceptions(Throwable t) {
    response.status = ((KomekException)t).getErrorCode();
    response.accessControl("*");
    response.contentType = "application/json";
    renderText(t.toString());
}
```